# How to change a field in a Dataframe based on the values in another Dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

A change at work has meant that our old department numbers will no longer be used and we will be using new department numbers in the next month.  However; we still need to keep track of the old department names for older data - the department numbers will not be changed retroactively.

I am working with two different spreadsheets.  One has the current department information and the other is the crosswalk from old department number to new department number.

What I need to do is take the data for the old department numbers (Cost Center and Cost Center Name) and update the old department numbers to the new ones based on the crosswalk spreadsheet and then add those rows back into the original spreadsheet.

```
## Crosswalk
import pandas as pd

## Read in the ScorecardDepartments
## Set index to False
ambDF = pd.read_excel('ScorecardDepartments.xlsx','Departments',index=False)

crossDF = pd.read_excel('Crosswalk.xlsx',index=False)

## Only select rows that have departments in the Scorecard
ambDF = ambDF.loc[ambDF['Include in Scorecard'] == 'Y']

## Set Column Dept to int
pd.to_numeric(ambDF['Dept'])

ambDF = ambDF.sort_values(by=['Dept'])
crossDF = crossDF.sort_values(by=['Dept'])
## Change Crosswalk Dept column to a list
## to use in comparison
Departments = crossDF['Dept'].tolist()

## Create a new dataframe with just the 
## the dept information 
changeRows = ambDF.loc[ambDF['Dept'].isin(Departments)]

## Join the two dataframes
frames = [ambDF,changeRows]
result = pd.concat(frames,sort=True)

result.to_excel('tmp.xlsx')
```

UPDATE:  I joined the two dataframes together, but that just gave me one large dataframe without the columns I need from the changeRows dataframe.  Also, the columns are not in the correct order.

Comment: Is a join between two data-frames enough? If yes, syntax and details can be found in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm very new to Python, but that looks good.  I'll give it a try. Thanks.